# TIBCO SPOTFIRE KPI

Tags: spotfire, tibco, kpi, spotfire-analyst

i have a kpi depending on a property setting (check-box). Then in the check-box list i have two different value: a, b (corresponding to the values in column propertycolumn).

Depending on this value i want to calculate a kpi value in this way: SUM of the amaunt with propertycolumn = DocumentProperty("property1") (a or b) / sum of the total amount (propertycolumn = a + propertycolumn =b).

1. If i do: Data -> Limit data using expression [property1 column]=DocumentProperty("property1")
   i can sum only on the filterd values. I.e
2. If i remove Limit data using expression i have two different KPIs (but i want only one kpi depending on the checkbox selected value).